# How do I get rid of this "argument requires that borrow lasts for `'1`" error?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm writing my first Rust program, implementing a simple LruCache and processing some events.

The LruCache is used in a closure, to keep track of events that have been processed after polling them, and to skip them, if they have already been processed:

```rust
let mut evt_cache = LruSetCache::new(100_000);

// poll for events
loop {

    let unprocessed_events: Vec<Event> = unprocessed_events_serialized
        .into_iter()
        .filter_map(|evt| {
            let key = evt.as_bytes();

            if evt_cache.exists(&key) {
                None
            } else {
                evt_cache.put(key.clone());
                Some(Event::from_bytes(&evt.as_bytes()).unwrap())
            }
        })
        .collect();

    // ... process events

}
```

However, the compiler is not happy with the way I pass the `[u8]` key to the cache:

```
  --> src/main.rs:58:27
   |
51 |     let mut evt_cache = LruSetCache::new(100_000);
   |         ------------ lifetime `'1` appears in the type of `evt_cache`
...
58 |                 let key = evt.as_bytes();
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
63 |                     evt_cache.put(key);
   |                     ----------------- argument requires that `evt` is borrowed for `'1`
...
66 |             })
   |             - `evt` dropped here while still borrowed
```

LruSetCache could be the culprit:

```rust
use std::collections::{HashSet, VecDeque};
use std::hash::Hash;

/// A LruCache that stores values (instead of (key, values) pairs).
///
/// You can
/// - insert elements,
/// - check for existence of an item.
/// It automatically frees memory after max_capacity is reached.
///
/// Basically, an LRUCache Backed by an `HashSet` instead of an `HashMap` that saves (little) memory and (very few) cpu cycles.
pub struct LruSetCache<T> {
    /// Elements will start to be evicted from the cache when this number of elements is reached.
    ///
    /// Note: In theory, we could avoid having this field here and keep track of the capacity by
    /// initializing the underlying `items` with `HashSet::with_capacity()` and by querying
    /// `HashSet::capacity()` when needed. However, if this inner detail implementation of `HashSet`
    /// that grows the capacity and starts re-allocating when the element is close to being full
    /// (rather than being full), then the LruCache would break.
    capacity: usize,

    /// Tracks which elements were added first, because they'll need to be removed when the
    /// maximum capacity is reached.
    /// Keeps track of the current capacity (`items.len()`).
    items: VecDeque<T>,

    /// Allows fast item existence check (O(1) as opposed to O(n) with the above VecDeque).
    items_set: HashSet<T>,
}

impl<T> LruCache<T> {
    pub fn new(capacity: usize) -> LruCache<T> {
        LruCache {
            capacity,
            items: VecDeque::with_capacity(capacity),
            items_set: HashSet::with_capacity(capacity),
        }
    }

    /// Checks whether an item exists.
    pub fn exists(&self, item: &T) -> bool {
        self.items_set.get(item).is_some()
    }

    /// Inserts an item.
    pub fn put(&mut self, item: T) {
        if self.items.len() >= self.capacity {
            // evict item that was inserted least recently
            self.items.pop_back();
            self.items_set.remove(&item);
        }

        self.items.push_front(&item);
        self.items_set.insert(&item);
    }
}
```

## My debugging journey so far

I passed ownership to the `LruCache::put` function, by specifying a `T` parameter instead of a `&T` like in `LruSetCache::set` but that doesn't seem to be enough for Rust to make it survive after the closure ends. It's my understanding that the `move` only creates another pointer to the original value, so I understand why this is not enough.

So I've tried `.clone()`ing the string before passing it in. I understand the error is the `[u8]` key will get out of memory when the closure ends. However, cloning it anew, and passing that instead, doesn't help.

I'm guessing it's because it gets cloned in the stack, instead of the heap where it can escape the function cleanup.

So I've tried `Box`ing the key, so it would exist in the heap instead of the stack and not be cleaned up when the function returns. But I get basically the same error message:

```rust
    let key = Box::new(evt.as_bytes());
```

```
53 |     let mut evt_cache = LruSetCache::new(100_000);
   |         ------------- lifetime `'1` appears in the type of `evt_cache`
...
60 |                 let key = Box::new(evt.as_bytes());
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
65 |                     evt_cache.put(key);
   |                     ------------------ argument requires that `eat` is borrowed for `'1`
...
68 |             })
   |             - `evt` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Rust wants the `evt` to outlive the closure for some reason, but I only need the key to do that.

What's going on here?

Comment: The error you posted points to code that's different than the first example you gave?

I'm not sure what the type of key is here: `let key = evt.as_bytes();`, but you might be able to try `let key = evt.as_bytes().to_vec();`, and insert the vec into your cache. This will clone the entire key, so probably won't be desirable if your key is very big.

Comment: @8176135 yes, thank you for reporting! I've updated it now. You're right, `.to_vec()` seems to work. Don't they both do the same here?  I've gone into the std library and I see `.clone()` implemented like: `impl<T: ?Sized> Clone for &T { fn clone(&self) -> Self { *self } }`which kind of explains why it doesn't work. It wasn't doing anything! Why wasn't `.clone()` implemented as `.to_vec()` in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `.clone()` with either `.to_owned()` or `.to_vec()`.

```
let unprocessed_events: Vec<Event> = unprocessed_events_serialized
    .into_iter()
    .filter_map(|evt| {
        let key = evt.as_bytes().to_owned(); // add `.to_vec()` or `.to_owned()`

        if evt_cache.exists(&key) {
            None
        } else {
            evt_cache.put(key); // Can remove .clone()
            Some(Event::from_bytes(&evt.as_bytes()).unwrap())
        }
    })
    .collect();
```

This will clone the entire key, so probably won't be desirable if your key is very big.

The version above will *always* clone the entire key, even if it already exists in evt_cache. This limitation can (probably) be lifted if the `.exists()` function is generic over `Borrow<T>` instead of just taking in a reference. (see how `HashSet::contains` is defined https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.contains). This way you only need to call `.to_owned()` on `evt_cache.put`.

---

> Shouldn't `.clone()` and `.to_vec()` do the same thing here?

The clone trait is defined in a way where we can't produce a different type from the one that is passed in. This causes problems for types like `&[T]`, `&str`, `Path` etc. which is solved with the additional `ToOwned` trait.

From https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html

> A generalization of Clone to borrowed data.
>
> Some types make it possible to go from borrowed to owned, usually by implementing the Clone trait. But Clone works only for going from &T to T. The ToOwned trait generalizes Clone to construct owned data from any borrow of a given type.

So the `.to_owned()` for `&[u8]` does do what you expect, it just calls `.to_vec()`

https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/slice.rs.html#838-862

Comment: Marked as solved, thanks! Another doubt: I've changed to signature of `exists()` to try and avoid a copy as you suggested, but it still complains if I don't use `.to_vec()` there. Any advice on what else to do in order to go from `copy`ing the value to `move`ing it?